# Azure fails release when zip file can't be located

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In my Azure release pipeline I have a task that extracts a zip file. But the zip file isn't always available. I've set my other tasks to continue when the zip extraction fails but the release status states: `failed`:

[image: re]

Comment: **Why** isn't the file always available? That sounds like a big problem.

Comment: It's per design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditions on a task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

```
if (Test-Path -path ***.zip) {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filesExists;]yes"
}
```

I'm using `and(always(),variables['fileExists'])` In a task I check if the zip files exist to set the value.